# ScrollTable not using value tag

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, seam, richdatatable

In a `ScrollTable` I need to retrieve data from a particular object and set data to another. How can I do this?

Now I find:

```
Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
```

The h:inputText has value tag = myBean.castData(getTopdata(par1))

Damn! I need only to get a value to display and not to set modifications (because the modifications are taken using a valueChangeListener).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself putting an hashmap between real data and displayed data.